# How to handle big data element in c++?

Tags: c++, pow

I want to divide the return value of `pow(2.0,(n-8))` by 86399.
The problem is `10 <= n <= 100000000`.

How can I handle such a large return value?

I'm on Ubuntu 11.10 64 bits, using C++ 4.0.0-8

Comment: Don't yell at us, please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This discussion should answer your question [Modular Exponentiation for high numbers in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2207006/modular-exponentiation-for-high-numbers-in-c)

For numbers that large, you'll have to do something clever. There's no way you can represent that full number naively in any reasonable way without bigint libraries, and even then it's really too big for brute force.  The number itself would take up tens of megabytes.

Comment: how the biginteger class of java is able to handle large integers?

Answer (score 4):

You can't unless you use a big numbers library.  64 bits can't hold a number that big.  And even then, it will probably take a while.  2^(86392) has about 26000 digits in it.

If you want to get just a modulus, there are some nice algorithms for that.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation.

If you want to try bignums still, check out http://gmplib.org/.

Answer (score 1):

One very easy way would be to use GMP -- http://gmplib.org/