# Simple Modular Exponentiation in C++ without overflow?

Tags: c++

I have to create a simple modular exponentiation function that takes input three integers, a, b and c, and performs the task: a^b %c without overflow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modular Exponentiation for high numbers in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2207006/modular-exponentiation-for-high-numbers-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is [Modular exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation). Assuming unsigned `a`, `b`, `c` and that `a * (c - 1)` does not overflow:

```
unsigned int r = 1;
for (unsigned int k = 0; k < b; k++)
    r = r * a % c;
```

(Note that there is no power operator in C, `^` is for `XOR` (exclosive `OR`.)

Comment: That's not really safe though, `r * a` could easily overflow. Also slow.

Comment: So the answer to a^b %c is r after k=b?

Comment: @harold Yes, I assumed a bit simplified case with reasonable `a`. Updated. I think the idea of the exercise was to avoid overflow related to exponentiation, not to focus on corner cases. But still, your remark is correct.

Comment: @Bartholomew Yes, `r` is supposed to be the result.

Comment: @AlexD Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Euler theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) for this, it can reduce the exponent down significantly.

You'll need a helper function for finding the phi function (or there might be a library with that in it).  Then, all you have to do is

```
(a ^ b) % c => (a ^ (b % phi(c)) % c
```

That will definitely help reduce the chance of overflow.  Further, mod has this property:

```
a*b % c = (a % c)*b % c
```

This means if your exponent will cause an overflow, you can half you exponent, and perform the mod on a smaller value.  Look into some number theory books for more tricks to make this easier!

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.