# Calculating pow(a,nCr) % m efficiently

Tags: combinatorics

I think there are some process for calculating pow(a,nCr)%b?
But I want to know how I can efficiently solve this problem in programming?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modulus power of big numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287144/modulus-power-of-big-numbers)

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a way that's only `~O(n^2*log(m))` and doesn't require the use of big integers. I have a notion of a faster (something like `O(k*log(m)*log(n))`) approach if you can factor `m` and you can factor [totient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function)(`m/gcd(a^k,m)`) for some `k`, but it gets pretty hairy.

In any case for the `O(n^2*log(m))` approach, we'll make use of the fact that nCr == (n-1)C(r-1) + (n-1)Cr

Here's a computation of nCr which exploits that:

```
def nCr(n0,r0):
  memoized = {}

  def go(n,r):
    if r == 0 or r == n:
      return 1
    if (n,r) not in memoized:
      memoized[(n,r)] = go(n-1,r-1) + go(n-1,r)
    return memoized[(n,r)]

  return go(n0,r0)
```

The code for your `powChooseMod` function would be almost identical:

```
def powChooseMod(a,n0,r0,m):
  memoized = {}

  def go(n,r):
    if r == 0 or r == n:
      return a
    if (n,r) not in memoized:
      memoized[(n,r)] = go(n-1,r-1) * go(n-1,r) % m
    return memoized[(n,r)]

  return go(n0,r0)
```