# Large integer operation in Python

Tags: python, math, rsa, largenumber

I'm trying to solve a cryptography CTF challenge which involves taking the building blocks of an RSA key-pair (two large primes) and the encrypted cipher number of a message. In order to decrypt this message, I need to carry out operations which I don't believe are supported by standard crypto libraries, as the public exponent used is unknown, but I do have the values `dp` and `dq`, meaning I have to carry out the following operations:

[image]

So essentially I'm raising very large integers to the power of very large integers, and the standard option of `pow(x,y)` causes Python to hang seemingly indefinitely. Without the use of crypto libraries then, how can I carry out these operations in Python?

Edit:
Here is the specific code and values causing Python to hang

```
p = 7901324502264899236349230781143813838831920474669364339844939631481665770635584819958931021644265960578585153616742963330195946431321644921572803658406281
dp = 5540655028622021934429306287937775291955623308965208384582009857376053583575510784169616065113641391169613969813652523507421157045377898542386933198269451
c = 62078086677416686867183857957350338314446280912673392448065026850212685326551183962056495964579782325302082054393933682265772802750887293602432512967994805549965020916953644635965916607925335639027579187435180607475963322465417758959002385451863122106487834784688029167720175128082066670945625067803812970871

m1 = pow(c,dp)%p
```

Comment: What exactly hangs? `pow(2790, 53) % 61` takes about 1 microsecond on my machine, and `pow(2790, 53, 61)` (which is probably what you want to use) is about 20% faster than that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modulus power of big numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287144/modulus-power-of-big-numbers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pow` takes an optional third argument `z`, that does a modulus operation, but is way faster than using the `%` operator:

```
>>> pow(c, dp, p)
49437413074993986257824490238275931180994249527518860068137626874351971280859988288289074
```