# How to read and assign big integers in C?

Tags: c

I am trying to assign big integer value to a variable in c and when I print I only get 10123456.

What is the issue?

```
  int main(){
      long a = 1234567890123456;
      printf("\n",sizeof(a));
      printf("%ld",a); 
  }
```

Comment: `long` isn't that long, try `long long`

Comment: What prints `printf("\n",sizeof(a));` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124332/c-handling-very-large-integers

Comment: Use `long long int` or some compiler specific types like `__int64` or `int64_t`.

Comment: Do not post code without compiling & running on your side.

Comment: @nishant what's wrong? It compiles and may have specified results. On 32bit compiler, obviously.

Comment: @keltar: Look at the comment by _nouney_

Answer (score 6):

Largest integer type is:

```
unsigned long long
```

dont forget about ULL suffix.
or if you need larger integers, take a look for some bigint libraries like [gmp](http://gmplib.org/).

Of course, there is also `long long`, but it is also for negative integers and have smaller limits.

```
 Type                min                      max

 (signed) long long  -9223372036854775808     9223372036854775807
 unsigned long long  0                        18446744073709551615
```

Comment: In C 1999 and later, the largest integer types described by the standard are `intmax_t` and `uintmax_t`. They are at least as large as `unsigned long long` and might be larger.

Answer (score 2):

```
long a = 1234567890123456L;
```

If long is long enough, depends on compiler/OS. If not

```
long long a = 1234567890123456LL;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the number is greater than 64-bit, i.e. longer than what `unsigned long long` can hold, then no data type in C other than string(`char[]`) will be able to accomodate that value, store it as a string & try writing your own functions to operate (e.g. add, subtract, etc.) on these "very large numbers".

Comment: There is no `string` in C

Comment: @Zaffy I know, that's why I wrote string(`char[]`), sorry for writing _string_ as a `code`.

Comment: @Zaffy C11 7.1.1 1 "Definitions of terms.  A _string_ is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character. ..."

Comment: @Chux I meant `string` datatype.

Comment: It is not generally true that an integer greater than what fits into 64 bits is not representable in some integer type in C. C 1999 and later provides for a variety of integer types, and an implementation may provide integer types of any size.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil: I didn't know that, thanks for the heads up. Can you please share some example of those data types, or give some link or other resource, where I can read more about them.

Comment: @nishant: Clause 7.20 of [the C standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) describes the `stdint.h` headers, which describes types such as `intmax_t` and `uintmax_t` for integers of the greatest width in the implementation, along with types for specific widths, macros for writing constants of the various types, and other embellishments. The `inttypes.h` header in clause 7.8 provides format specifiers for using the types with `printf`.