# Large Number Storage

Tags: c++, math, rsa

I am trying to implement the [RSA Key Generation algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28cryptosystem%29#Key_generation) for a school project. I am having trouble with the encryption stage of the algorithm. It requires me to raise a user inputted integers to the power of a random number (random number has a criteria) and these random numbers are usually 2 or 3 digits long; eg. `23^239 = d`. In most situations, the 'd' value is 100s of digits long and I cannot find anything to store it as. I have tried `long long` but the return value is always negative.

How can I generate and store very large numbers?

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124332/c-handling-very-large-integers

Comment: [boost::multiprecision](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/intro.html) is a solution for big numbers.

Comment: if the answer helps you, accept it. It'll help both you and the answerer have more reputations

Answer (score 4):

All exponentiation in RSA is modular exponentiation. That is, you'll never just compute `23^239`... instead, you'll compute something like `23^239 mod 11`. You *could* calculate the exponentiation, and then calculate the modulus.... but as you've seen, that requires the ability to represent a pretty big number. Instead, one does the two operations at the same time; this is much more efficient, and does not require much storage space.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation for more details, and algorithms.

(Note that, ordinarily, you would *still* need a bigint library for RSA, because you'd be working with numbers hundreds of digits long, not 2 or 3 digits long. The assignment here seems to have been designed to keep you from having to do that, though.)