# Double multiplication giving rounded results

Tags: c++, double, multiplication

```
double a = 2451550;
double b = .407864;
double c= a*b;
cout<<c;
```

I was expecting the results to be "999898.9892" but getting "999899". I need the actual unrounded result.Please suggest.

Comment: http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: would assume that it some sort of rounded tit up

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/117429/inputting-large-numbers-in-c

Answer (score 14):

By default, iostreams output 6 digits of precision.  If you want more, you have to ask for it:

```
std::cout.precision(15);
```

Comment: Thanks, but the actual problem is, i want to use "c" result for other computation and not just for display.

Comment: @Vikas: read the answer again - you are already getting the precision that you need - you're just getting confused because of the way that you are displaying the value.

Comment: You will get 52 bits of precision but it won't be "exact" due to how floating point arithmetic works.

Answer (score 1):

It can also be done using Manipulator setprecision like below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 double a = 2451550;
 double b = .407864;
 double c= a*b;
 cout<<setprecision(15)<<c;
}
```

Also, Usage of manipulator will make the code compact.

Answer (score 0):

By default the precision of an std::iostream will show how many digits *total* to display and by default precision is 6.  So, since your number has six digits *before* the decimal place it will not display any after the decimal.

You can change this behavior with the 'fixed' manipulator.  'precision' then changes to mean the number of digits to display *after* the decimal which is probably what you were expecting.

To always get four digits after the decimal you can do this:

```
cout << setprecision(4) << fixed << c;
```

However, keep in mind that this will always display four digits after the decimal even if they are zeros.  There is no simple way to get 'precision' to mean *at most* x number of digits after the decimal place with std::iostreams.