# Types in C++ for large numbers

Tags: c++

I want to calculate the number of inversions for a very big array, something like 200,000 ints, and the number I get is quite big. So big it can't be stored in an `int` value.

The answer I get is something like -8,353,514,212, while for simple cases it works, so I think that the problem is the type of the variable I use to store the number of inversions.

I also tried with `long int` and the output is the same, but if I try with `double` 4.0755e+009 is the output. I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: Have you tried using `unsigned long long`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/117429/inputting-large-numbers-in-c

Comment: `unsigned long long` will take you far enough to store the number of inversions in arrays of `6*10^9` elements or so.

Comment: `18.446.744.073.709.551.615` on 64-bit OS

Comment: unsigned long long did the job thanks a lot !

Answer (score 3):

1. use an unsigned data type
2. use `unsigned long` (usually 2^32-1) or `unsigned long long` (usually 2^64-1)

For full reference see [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_%28computer_science%29).

Comment: The size of these `unsigned long` and `unsigned long long` are platform specific. It would be good to mention this in you answer.

Comment: @KirilKirov Yes, but the given numbers are the smallest allowed maximal values. If the types are actually larger, nothing's lost.

Comment: @DanielFischer - it's true, but still, this could be misleading for someone.

Answer (score 0):

If the native types of the compiler aren't fit to hold the result of your computation, you could consider using a bignum library.

A quick search revealed these two:

http://www.ttmath.org/

http://gmplib.org/

I've no experience with either, but gmp seems to be the more popular choice around SO, so maybe that's what you should try first