# Adding two strings arithmetically

Tags: c++, string

I'm trying to implement a function to add two overly large (let's say 1000 digit long) numbers stored in strings. I'm having problems with correct conversions so I can add numbers correctly.

So far, this is what I've done:

```
string addBegin (string low, string high, int diff)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= diff; i++)
        low = "0" + low;
    high = "0" + high;

    cout << "low: " << low << "\nhigh: " << high << endl;

    string result;
    int sum, carry = 0;

    for (int i = low.length()-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        sum = (int)low[i] + (int)high[i] + carry;
        carry = 0;
        if (sum > 9)
        {
            sum -= 10;
            carry = 1;
        }
        result = to_string(sum) + result;
    }

    return result;
}

string add (string a, string b)
{
    int diff = a.length() - b.length();

    if (diff <= 0) return addBegin(a, b, abs(diff));
    else return addBegin(b, a, diff);
}

int main (void)
{
    string x = add("52","205");
    cout << "result: " << x << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
low: 0052
high: 0205 //the first zero is for potential carry
result: 87899293 //wrong, should be 0257
```

The result here is made of 4 numbers: `87`, `89`, `92` and `93`. That is obviously wrong, I did some unwanted additions with ASCII values. Any ideas how to make this work? Or is there, by any chance, some ridiculously simple way to add two veeeeery long numbers?

Comment: pls help me understand, is `result = low + high`, if they are integers, not strings? and is the only caveat is the numbers are `"veeeeery long"`?

Comment: When approaching such problems, try to think in small numbers. For example, what should the algorithm do in order to add 5+4? and then, 75+46?

Comment: i am unable to understand, so just asking -- if all you want to do is add two large numbers, why cann't you use them as big integers (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/117429/inputting-large-numbers-in-c#117472) instead of string, and do addition?

Comment: @Bill A bigint is just a string in another numeric base :) This is a common exercise.

Comment: @IlyaKogan Sure, but I don't think that's the main issue here. If I were to add up 75+46, I'd like to get sum of 5+6 and not the sum of their ASCII values.

Comment: Yes, but does your program work with 5+6? You're testing it with 52+205 before trying small numbers, but small numbers will be easier to debug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    sum = (int)low[i] + (int)high[i] + carry;
```

This adds the values of the character encodings in e.g. ASCII. You want to subtract `'0'` from the encoding to get the numeric value.

```
    sum = low[i] - '0' + high[i] - '0' + carry;
```

Comment: Aaaaand. Working solution is born. I remember doing something similar, but not entirely correct it seems. Thanks.

Comment: I suspect an extra leading '0' is in the result, you may need to conditionally remove it.

Comment: @chux Yes, I'm well aware of that. Thanks. ;)

Answer (score 4):

Do not forget subtracting `'0'` from `low[i]` and `high[i]` when doing the math.

`(int)low[i]` is `0x30`..`0x39` for chars `'0'`..`'9'`.

Answer (score 1):

A problem is that you use

```
sum = (int)low[i] + (int)high[i] + carry;
```

which should be

```
sum = low[i] - '0' + high[i] - '0' + carry;
```