# Data type in c++ or java for holding 20 digit integer

Tags: java, c++, abstract-data-type

Is there any data type available in Java or C++ which can hold integer values of 20 digits or more? The long long data type can hold only till 18 digits.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Java specific:

You are looking for [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)

> Immutable arbitrary-precision integers. All operations behave as if BigIntegers were represented in two's-complement notation (like Java's primitive integer types)

For ex:

```
  BigInteger bint = new BigInteger("1234567856656569");
  BigInteger bint2 = new BigInteger("1234556567856656569");
  System.out.println(bint2.intValue()-bint.intValue()); //397189120
```

And [`BigDecimal`](http://www.opentaps.org/docs/index.php/How_to_Use_Java_BigDecimal%3a_A_Tutorial)

Comment: You shouldn't use intValue() because it can overflow. Instead use the built in operations like add(), subtract() and so on. Remember that BigIntegers are immutable so you must asign the returned value to a variable.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at java [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html).

Answer (score 3):

In `java` you can use:

- `BigInteger`: for numbers without decimal values
- `BigDecimal`: for numbers with decimal values

Answer (score 3):

Check out [The Large Integer Case Study in C++.pdf](http://apcentral.collegeboard.com/apc/public/repository/ap01.pdf.lr_7928.pdf) by Owen Astrachan. I found this file extremely useful with detail introduction and code implementation. It doesn't use any 3rd-party library. I have used this to handle huge numbers (as long as you have enough memory to store `vector<char>`) with no problems.

I have answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/117429/handling-large-numbers-in-c/20754900#20754900), where I gave a more detailed introduce.

Comment: While implementing arbitrary-precision integer arithmetic using strings is useful from an educational perspective, you're likely to get much better performance from Boost.Multiprecision, which itself support multiple backends.

Answer (score 3):

For C++, you can check out Matt McCutchen's [Big Integer](https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/) class, for Java just use BigInteger

Answer (score 2):

`BigInteger` class in Java can hold such numbers.

Alternatively, you can implement your own class, based on two long long numbers.

Answer (score 1):

For C++, see Boost's excellent [multiprecision library](http://www.boost.org/libs/multiprecision/).

Answer (score 1):

Use BigInt datatype with its implicit operations

Here is an example of addition

```
      BigInteger big1 = new BigInteger("1234567856656567242177779");
      BigInteger big2 = new BigInteger("12345565678566567131275737372777569");
      BigInteger bigSum = big1.add(big2);
      System.out.println(bigSum );
```