# Money counter for application/game

Tags: java

I'm converting my money pouch to hold more than the max integer. I'm stuck here:

```
public String getFormattedValue(double value) {
    if (value >= 1000 && value < 10e+5) {
        return formatValue(value / 1000, 2) + "k";
    } else if (value >= 10e+5 && value <= 10e+8) {
        return formatValue(value / 10e+5, 3) + " million";
    } else if (value >= 10e+8 && value <= ***?***) {
        return formatValue(value / 10e+8, 3) + " billion";
    } else if (value >= ***?*** && value <= ***??***) {
        return formatValue(value / 10e+8, 3) + " trillion";
    } else {
        return formatValue(value, 2);
    }
}
```

`***?***` should = 1 billion & `***??***` should = 1 trillion. I'm confused because I'm not the brightest with math & google wont format it for me.

What's the mathematical equation like "10e+8" = 1 million to get 1 billion.

Comment: Try using long instead.

Comment: As Luggi suggested long is there and even there is BigInteger : Might Helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20772486/data-type-in-c-or-java-for-holding-20-digit-integer

Comment: *What's the mathematical equation like "10e+8" = 1 million to get 1 billion* => `1000000000L`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the formatValue function, but I think you can do something like the following:

```
public String getFormattedValue(double value)
{

   long thousands = (long)(value / 1000);
   long millions = (long)(value / 1000000);
   long billions = (long)(value / 1000000000);
   long trillions = (long)(value / 1000000000000L);


   if (trillions > 0)
       return formatValue(trillions) + " trillion";
   else if (billions > 0)
       return formatValue(billions) + " billion";
   else if (millions > 0)
       return formatValue(millions) + " million";
   else if (thousands > 0)
       return formatValue(thousands) + " k";

   else
       return ("" + value);
}
```