# Using very big number

Tags: c++, int

I am looking to use very big numbers (up to 255 figures in one variable) and manipulating these values on basic level (+, -, *, /, ^ and √) in C++ but I am not sure whether using `bigInt` (https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/) will handle such big numbers.

Comment: https://www.google.com/#q=arbitrary+precision+library+c%2B%2B

Comment: Citing the linked page: _"You can use this library in a C++ program to do arithmetic on integers of size limited only by your computer's memory"_. I bet that your computer has enough memory to handle 255 figures, and even more! But note that this library is only for _integer_, not fractions or decimals, hence the name,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/117429/handling-large-numbers-in-c/20754900#20754900), I will recommend you to check out [**The Large Integer Case Study in C++.pdf**](http://apcentral.collegeboard.com/apc/public/repository/ap01.pdf.lr_7928.pdf) by Owen Astrachan. I found this file extremely useful with detail introduction and code implementation. It doesn't use any 3rd-party library. I have used this to handle huge numbers (as long as you have enough memory to store `vector<char>`) with no problems.

---

**Idea**:
It implements an arbitrary precision integer class by storing big int in a `vector<char>`.

```
vector<char> myDigits; // stores all digits of number
```

Then all operations related to the big int, including `<<, >>, +, -, *, ==, <, !=, >, etc.`, can be done based on operations on this `char array`.

---

**Edit**: Btw, `bigInt` is fine too.

Comment: It _is_ a third-party library.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You mean the one by Owen Astrachan?

Comment: The provided solution was enough to start establishing foundations on my project. The situation is such that the project can be the whole solution so importing 3rd party library is not a problem. I think using such method will do the work. Many thanks!

Comment: @user3141651 Good to go. :)

Answer (score 1):

i'll suggest you to use GMP (https://gmplib.org). it's work with arbitrary length numbers.