# factorial of N where N is greater then 200

Tags: c++

Is there any way to calculate the factorial of N, where N>200.Is there something like Bigdata in c++.Since even a long variable cannot store such a big number.can you please tell me any approach to deal with such big number problems????

Comment: Not in standard C++, but there are libraries out there just waiting.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12988099/big-numbers-library-in-c

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/117429/handling-large-numbers-in-c and, I'm sure, a dozen others... google would have saved you time.

Comment: The [GNU GMP](https://gmplib.org/) library is popular, as is OpenSSL's [BN](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/bn.html).

Answer (score 1):

int or long types are not big enough for the values you're talking about.

34! = 295232799039604140847618609643520000000

This barely fits into 128 bits. If your compiler supports a 128-bit number type, you can use it to calculate factorials up to 34. If not, or if you need anything larger, you will need to use some kind of [bignum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bignum) library.

See this question for [bignum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bignum) libraries:
[Big numbers library in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12988099/big-numbers-library-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

I implemented a BigInteger for C++. You are welcome to use it.

http://memmove.blogspot.com/2013/04/unlimited-unsigned-integer-in-c.html